# getting attentionwrapper issue in spellchecker program

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://github.com/Currie32/Spell-Checker.

In the above link code I'm getting error that DynamicAttentionWrapper is not defined. I'm using TensorFlow version as 1.2. I couldn't able to over come with this error. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with `DynamicAttentionWrapper` in your version of `tensorflow`.

Try changing `DynamicAttentionWrapper` to `AttentionWrapper` or downgrade to `tensorflow 1.1`.

For your version of `tensorflow`, try these changes for `initial_state, inference_logits and training_logits`:

```
initial_state = dec_cell.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size,dtype=tf.float32).clone(cell_state=enc_state)

inference_logits, _ ,_ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(inference_decoder,
output_time_major=False,
impute_finished=True,
maximum_iterations=max_target_length)

training_logits, _ ,_ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(training_decoder,
output_time_major=False,
impute_finished=True,
maximum_iterations=max_target_length)
```